Connection Timeout for AWS-S3 Repository by Elasticsearch
I want to save my backups in AWS,below is my elastic for my docker compose that is run and up and work well and i add to enviornment into this configuration:
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: focker.ir/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.13.4
    container_name: ${CONT_NAME}
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: ${NODE_NAME}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 131072
        hard: 131072
      nproc: 8192
      fsize: -1
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      # HTTP/REST
      - 9201:9201/tcp
      - 9301:9301/tcp
    volumes:
      # mkdir /var/lib/elasticsearch && chown -R 1000:1000 /var/lib/elasticsearch
      - $PWD/var/lib/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - $PWD/etc/certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates
      - $PWD/etc/elasticsearch/backup:/usr/share/elasticsearch/backup
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: '-Xms12g -Xmx12g'
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}

      cluster.name: elastiflow
      node.name: ${NODE_NAME}

      bootstrap.memory_lock: 'true'

      network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
      network.publish_host: ${NETWORK_PUBLISH_HOST}

      http.port: 9201
      http.publish_port: 9201

      transport.port: 9301
      transport.publish_port: 9301

      discovery.seed_hosts: '${ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS_1},${ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS_2},${ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS_3}'
      cluster.initial_master_nodes: 'ES_NODE_NAME_1,ES_NODE_NAME_2,ES_NODE_NAME_3'

      indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 8192
      search.max_buckets: 250000

      action.destructive_requires_name: 'true'

      reindex.ssl.verification_mode: 'none'

      xpack.security.http.ssl.key: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/node.key
      xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/node.pem
      xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/root-ca-key.pem
      xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode: 'none'
      xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: 'true'

      xpack.security.transport.ssl.key: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/node.key
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/node.pem
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/root-ca-key.pem
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: 'none'
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: 'true'

      xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled: 'true'
      xpack.monitoring.collection.interval: 30s

      xpack.security.enabled: 'true'
      xpack.security.audit.enabled: 'false'

      path.repo: "/usr/share/elasticsearch/backup"

      s3.client.default.endpoint: "https://xxx.xxx.com"
      s3.client.default.protocol: "https"


and after it runs I do this into my docker container:
./bin/elasticsearch-keystore add s3.client.default.access_key
./bin/elasticsearch-keystore add s3.client.default.secret_key

and add my access and secret key,also I can see my bucket into S3
aws s3 ls --endpoint-url https://xxx.xxx.com

2024-06-06 12:10:46 datacenter


also I have this
curl -k -u 'elastic:mypassword' -X GET "https://x.x.x.x:9201/_snapshot/MY_AGG"

{"MY_AGG":{"type":"s3","settings":{"bucket":"datacenter","client":"default","base_path":"elasticsearch_snapshots","endpoint":"https://xxx.xxx.com","protocol":"https","region":"ams1"}}}

but when it creates I get for repository
{
  "name": "ResponseError",
  "message": "repository_verification_exception\n\tCaused by:\n\t\ti_o_exception: Unable to upload object [elasticsearch_snapshots/tests-b6qrbfGaQUOB0spM_IDTTQ/master.dat] using a single upload\n\tRoot causes:\n\t\trepository_verification_exception: [MY_AGG] path [elasticsearch_snapshots] is not accessible on master node"
}

and Verification status is not connected
also into my container after do
docker exec -it elastic_agg_1 /bin/bash

I get
curl -I https://xxx.xxx.com
HTTP/2 200
server: nginx
date: Thu, 06 Jun 2024 10:50:54 GMT
content-type: application/xml
x-amz-request-id: tx000009xxxxx238a-0xxxxx48e-16415a0a-xxx
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains

is there anyone to help me to solce my problem?
I do restart container after my changes,and I check my accessbility to aws by my network. And everything looks ok!
